# Sorting a list by a specific int

Tags: c#, visual-studio

```
 GameManager.inventory.item.Add(new Item("Health Potion  :", 2, 1));
```

the string is the itemName
the first int is the count
the last int is the iD

I would like to sort multiple itemName by id, but  i have no idea how to do it

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I presume this is a List so you can use List.Sort

check this question [sort a list by field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7873295/how-to-sort-a-list-by-field)

Comment: Yes that's what I as looking for, I didn't remember how it was done, thanks!